# Android Service Websockets NullPointerException

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, websocket

I am building a chat app in android powered by webscokets and XAMPP (for the moment). However, upon attempting to send the message, the app simply errors out and notes the error:

```
02-22 22:47:26.571    1439-1622/com.example.feastapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-140
    Process: com.example.feastapp, PID: 1439
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.specialSharing.SpecialSharing$4$1.run(SpecialSharing.java:259)
```

on the line `imService.sendMessage("user1","user2", "1", "0", "0") == null`.

I am binding the service to the class with (at the top of the class):

```
private Manager imService;

        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder) service).getService();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                imService = null;
                Toast.makeText(SpecialSharing.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

The problem I am facing is that I have used this code many times throughout my application to bind the service and then send messages using the method above.

Why now would the action produce a NullPointer? Why wouldn't the service work here?

```
public class SpecialSharing extends Activity {

    private Switch mapAppearSwitch;
    private TextView selectLocationText;
    private EditText enteredMessage;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LatLngBounds latLngBounds;
    private Button sendButton;
    private Button changeShareButton;
    private Integer shareType = 0;
    private String sharedSpecialId;
    private String selectedLocationId = null;

    private InfoOfGroup group = new InfoOfGroup();
    private InfoOfFriend friend = new InfoOfFriend();

    String getSpecialLocationURL = null;

    String specialLocationActionURL = "http://" + Global.getIpAddress()
            + ":3000/getSpecialLocations/";

    String JSON = ".json";
    JSONArray resultObject;

    ArrayList<String> locationIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> locationAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> locationCityList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> locationStateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> locationZipList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> locationLatitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> locationLongitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    String[] locationId = new String[locationIdList.size()];
    String[] locationAddress = new String[locationAddressList.size()];
    String[] locationCity = new String[locationCityList.size()];
    String[] locationState = new String[locationStateList.size()];
    String[] locationZip = new String[locationZipList.size()];
    Double[] locationLatitude = new Double[locationLatitudeList.size()];
    Double[] locationLongitude = new Double[locationLongitudeList.size()];

    private Manager imService;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder) service).getService();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(SpecialSharing.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sharing_action);

        // Get activity objects:
//        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.restaurantLocationMap);
//        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();


        mapAppearSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchLocationSharing);
        selectLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectLocationText);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendSharing);
        changeShareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeShareButton);
        enteredMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterMessage);

        // Get switch
        mapAppearSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchLocationSharing);

        // Initialize settings:
        mapAppearSwitch.setChecked(false);
        selectLocationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       // mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // Getting either the group or friend to share with:
        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        group.groupName = extras.getString(InfoOfGroup.GROUPNAME);
        group.groupId = extras.getString(InfoOfGroup.GROUPID);
        friend.userName = extras.getString(InfoOfFriend.USERNAME);
        //******** NEED FRIENDS USER ID ********

        // Getting the selected id:
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_SPECIAL_ID", 0);
        sharedSpecialId = settings.getString("specialId", "0");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Special shared id is " +specialId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Check if a group of friend sharing with, then set the button
        if (group.groupName != null) {
            changeShareButton.setText("Group: " + group.groupName);
            shareType = 0;
        } else if (friend.userName != null) {
            changeShareButton.setText(friend.userName);
            shareType = 1;
        }

        // Toggling location message or not
        mapAppearSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    selectLocationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    selectLocationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });


        // Change share button
        changeShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Have dialog to confirm, and open sharing back up
                // To select a different sharing

            }
        });

        // Send message
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (selectedLocationId == null) {
                    selectedLocationId = "0";
                }

                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            if (imService.sendMessage("user1",
                                    "user2", "1", "0", "0") == null) {

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    public void run() {

                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                });
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sharing_action, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you saw a 'Service Connected' toast before you clicked the button? Check if imService==null before using it and display a toast telling that.

Comment: The same for seeing the disconnecteld toast. Start Initialising your pointer to null at top of the class.